# How to generate .qm files from .ts files?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm currently using the command `lrelease file.ts` but getting an error as "The command "lrelease" is either misspelled or could not be found."

Referred this docu- https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#translation

Comment: For starters, you can translate the error message into English. Für den Anfang können Sie die Fehlermeldung ins Englische übersetzen.

Comment: If "lrelease" are already installed in your system, add path to lrelease to PATH system variable or use full path in your command. Otherwise install OSGeo4W for example. It contains this programm.

Comment: I'm running the command in OSGeo4W but still getting this error. Currently I don't have lrelease installed in my system.